# clearing dynamically created combo box options using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, combobox

- I have a combo box with one option hard coded.
- I will add the remaining options dynamically

Combo box with hard coded option:

```
<select id="connectionname" class="connectionname" onchange="display();"><option>---Select---</option></select>
```

Javascript function to create combo box options dynamically:

```
function showDbDlg(){
    var newar=new Array();
    try{
        var xhrArgs = {
                url: "./ReadDBDetails",
                content: {MODE:"DBNAMES"}, 
                handleAs: "text",
                load: function(response) {
                    var dbNames = response.trim();
                    dbNames=dbNames.substring(0,dbNames.length-1);
                    dbArray=dbNames.split(",");
                    /*var selectValue = document.getElementById("connectionname").value;
                    alert(selectValue);*/
                    document.getElementById("connectionname").options.length = 0;
                    for(var i=0;i<dbArray.length;i++){
                        var newValue = document.getElementById("connectionname").appendChild(document.createElement('option'));
                        newValue.text = dbArray[i];
                    }
                    formDialog.show();
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("An unexpected error occurred: " + error);
                }
        };
        var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
    }catch(e){alert(e);}

}
```

- Before creating options dynamically, every time am using the below line to clear the existing options.
- `document.getElementById("connectionname").options.length = 0;`
- Its clearing the hard coded option as well.
- My need is, i want to clear the dynamically created options alone.. not the hard coded one.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
document.getElementById("connectionname").options.length = 1;
```